# The correct way to use fscanf in C++

Tags: c++, io, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to read data from a csv file in the following format:

```
a_x,a_y,v_x,o_rear,o_front,theta,type
-0.040,10.206,-0.000,0.000,-0.000,-0.002,plane
1.269,9.813,0.011,0.043,0.091,-0.002,plane
1.266,9.985,0.021,0.086,0.177,-0.002,plane
1.257,10.002,0.032,0.130,0.265,-0.002,plane
1.256,10.004,0.043,0.173,0.353,-0.002,plane
1.257,10.003,0.053,0.216,0.440,-0.002,plane
1.258,10.002,0.064,0.259,0.527,-0.002,plane
1.258,10.002,0.074,0.302,0.615,-0.002,plane
```

I wrote the following code:-

```
FILE *in_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        int i=0, s=0;

        char *temp;
        fscanf(in_file,"%s",temp);
        printf("%s\n",temp);
        while(i<100){
            float a_x,a_y,v_x,o_rear,o_front,theta;
            char *type;
            if((s = fscanf(in_file,"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%[^,]",&a_x,&a_y,&v_x,&o_rear,&o_front,&theta,type))!=7)
                printf("%7d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%s\n",++i,s,a_x,a_y,v_x,o_rear,o_front,theta,type);
            else{
                printf("ALL GOOD: %7d\n",++i);
            }
        }
```

I am getting a segmentation fault. On running gdb, I found that it occurs on the `fscanf(in_file,"%s",temp);` line with the following error:-

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff71c6f64 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffda48, errp=errp@entry=0x0)
    at vfscanf.c:1107
1107    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Stacktrace:-

```
#0  0x00007ffff71c6f64 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffda48, 
    errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1107
#1  0x00007ffff71cce47 in ___vfscanf (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffda48) at vfscanf.c:3066
#2  0x00007ffff71d47b7 in __fscanf (stream=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at fscanf.c:31
#3  0x0000555555555186 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdc58) at data_handler.cpp:23
```

Surprisingly, when I use the `type` variable to dump the first line, I do not get any seg fault. Instead `fscanf` returns 7 for the first time and 0 then. Thus I can read the second row correctly, but not other rows. What am I doing wrong? I want to understand why such behaviour is happening.

Comment: `char *temp; fscanf(in_file,"%s",temp);` -- This is wrong.  You are reading into an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Did you assign a value to `temp`? If not, why are you passing its (nonsensical) value to `fscanf`?

Comment: But what happens when I declare `type` variable outside loop and use it instead?

Comment: @MeetTaraviya *But what happens when I declare type variable outside loop and use it instead* -- Why does that matter?  You declared a pointer that points to who-knows-where since it is uninitialized, and then you're reading characters into that space.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: We have an [MCVE requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - correct, but what about the remaining part? Why is it not reading in further lines?

Comment: @MeetTaraviya As soon as undefined behavior starts, there is no "remaining part".  It becomes a moot point.  You've already corrupted your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I corrected it, and it's still happening

Comment: *I corrected it, and it's still happening* -- You have several problems with your program, as you make the same mistake of using uninitialized pointer variables in other places, namely the other `fscanf` call.  Anyway, you're using C++, so why are you writing basically `C` code?

Comment: Does C++ has format specifiers?

Comment: If you used C++ streams, there is no need for format specifiers for what you're trying to read in.  C++ streams know what type you're trying to read into -- there is no need to tell the compiler `%f` or `%s`,

Comment: `char *temp;` -> `char temp[1000];`, where 1000 is the expected maximal line length of your file.

Answer (score 4):

**The idiomatic way to read from a file in C++ is with [`istream::operator>>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm), you can find the detailed documentation for that [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).**

It works much better and makes it harder to get segmentation faults and undefined behavior.

If you're intent upon solving this problem *the C way*, you should use a C compiler (and not a C++ compiler), this code should use the `.c` extension and this question should use the `[c]` tag.

Nonetheless, whether you're a C++ programmer or a C programmer you are *expected* to *read manuals*. There's [an `fscanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html), for example, which tells you how to use `fscanf` correctly and thus answers this question. It says:

> s   Matches a sequence of bytes that are not white-space characters. The application shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to the initial byte of **an array of `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`** large enough to accept the sequence and a terminating null character code, which shall be added automatically.

Though the manual pages provide emphasis, I've emphasized the most significant part that you need to understand here: `temp` needs to *point at something*!

**As it currently stands, your variable `temp` could point at *anything* or *nothing*.** For example, it could contain a *null pointer* value, meaning it'd point at *nothing*; you haven't told it to do otherwise, have you?

Change the declaration of `temp` like so:

```
char temp[512];             // ... or
char *temp = new char[512]; // ... etc
```

Either of these will ensure the expression `temp` in `fscanf(in_file, "%s", temp);` points at *an array*.

Comment: It's true that I am not doing it the *idiomatic way*. But what I want to do will be unnecessarily verbose and unreadable in the *idiomatic way*. It would have been easier if the file was space-separated and not comma-separated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `temp` in the call to `fscanf` without making sure that it points to some valid memory where data can be read to. This causes undefined behavior.

You can use:

```
// Use any number that is big enough for your needs
char temp[200];

// Make sure you provide the maximum number of characters to
// read to temp, always leaving space for the null terminator.
fscanf(in_file, "%199s", temp);
```

Comment: Then why does this does not give a seg fault:

Comment: FILE *in_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int i=0, s=0;

  char *type;
  fscanf(in_file,"%s",type);
  printf("%s\n",type);
  while(i<100){
   float a_x,a_y,v_x,o_rear,o_front,theta;
   // char *type;
   if((s = fscanf(in_file,"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%[^,]",&a_x,&a_y,&v_x,&o_rear,&o_front,&theta,type))!=7)
    printf("%7d,%d,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%s\n",++i,s,a_x,a_y,v_x,o_rear,o_front,theta,type);
   else{
    printf("ALL GOOD: %7d\n",++i);
   }
  }

Comment: @MeetTaraviya, undefined behavior, by definition,  cannot be defined. Anything can happen, including seemingly sane behavior. You can't try to make sense of it.

Comment: @MeetTaraviya `why does this does not give a seg fault` Undefined means undefined. It can give errors, it can appear to work, it can do any strange things, it can explode, ... just don't write UB code.

Answer (score 1):

As @PaulMcKenzie pointed out, I did not initialize my pointers. So I used `char x[100]` everywhere instead of `char *x`. The other problem was wrong format string: It should be `"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%s"` instead of `"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%[^,]"`